# Should a compactly supported field have a Helmotz decomposition that is compactly supported?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, contour-integration, cross-product, stokes-theorem

Let $\bf F$ be a smooth vector field, which is null outside a finite compact domain $V$. By Helmoltz decomposition thm, there exist a scalar field $\Phi$ and a vector field $\bf A$ such that
$${\bf F} = \nabla \Phi + \nabla \times {\bf A}.$$

For me, it's seems unlikely that smooth fields $\Phi$ and $\bf A$ which are null outside $V$ cannot be found to satisfy this identity, but I have troubles to prove that. Any idea?

Comment: $Helmo\color{red}{l}tz$

Answer (score 1):

The Helmotz decomposition theorem actually says that, a vector field $F\in L^2(V)$ could be decomposed into $F=A+\nabla\Phi$ where the normal component of vector field $A$ vanishes on $\partial V$ (in the sense of trace) and $\Phi\in H^1(\Omega)$.

Therefore, $F$ vanishes on $\partial V$ must imply that the normal component of $\nabla\Phi$ vanishes on $\partial V$, and it does note necessarily imply that $\Phi$ vanishes on $\partial V$. In fact, if $\Phi$ satisfies the decomposition, then $\Phi+C$ also satisfies.

Reference: section 2.2 of Robinson's book *The Three-Dimensional
Navier–Stokes Equations*.

Comment: thx for answering me. I don't understand the meaning of "vanishing in the sense of trace". Also, what is $H^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Also, my question didn't reflect my thoughts correctly, so I have edited it. According to your answer, it seems that the answer is yes (since a constant can be subtraced to $\Phi$ and $\bf A$.

Comment: @MikeTeX $H^1(\Omega)$ is Sobolev space. Maybe I should not mention it because it seems not related to your question...

Comment: what about "vanishing in the sense of trace"?

Comment: @MikeTeX It just means 'vanish on the boudary'. We need the new terminogy because an $H^1$ function is defined in the a.e. sense, and has no meaning on the boundary since the boundary has measure zero. In this case, we need a 'trace operator' for extending the function onto the boundary. You can refer to chapter 5 of Evans' _Partial Differntial Equations_ for details.

Comment: OK, I understand. But this decomposition theorem is not the Helmholtz decomposition theorem actually. Does it have some name so that I can find a proof in the web, because Robinson's book is not easily available to me. Moreover, are we sure that your field A is solenoidal?

Comment: @MikeTeX Yeah, $A$ is solenoidal. The theorem I write is just Helmholtz decomposition in the weak sense.

Comment: thx. If so, I don't know this version according to which $A$ vanishes on $\partial V$. In the classic version, only the integral on this surface vanishes, but that not sufficient to show your assertion.

Comment: @MikeTeX Sorry... I make a mistake here. The theorem only says the normal component of $A$ vanishes on the boundary. I'd better rewrite my answer.